# Is it possible to run Mule flows in-memory without any container?

Tags: mule

Recently got to know about an article which talks about deploying Mule flows to JBoss container - https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/deploying-mule-to-jboss. Which is great, but is there a way I can run Mule just on top of java ?

There is a maven plugin for Apache Camel which allows that, for example I can just a create a Camel project and execute 'mvn camel run', which will bring up a camel instance on its own.

I am able to see some articles which talks about 'maven'izing Mule projects and of course there is a Mule maven plugin(https://github.com/mulesoft/maven-mule-plugin). But not sure if there is a plugin for running Mule flows standalone.

It doesn't need to be a maven plugin as such, if there is a technical possibility to package the mule flows + required mule libraries in a jar and execute the jar to run on its own ? Thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, you can bootstrap Mule from simple Java code by building the MuleContext and loading your Spring XML config files. Simple example:

```
DefaultMuleContextFactory muleContextFactory =
new DefaultMuleContextFactory();
SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder("mule-config.xml");
MuleContext muleContext = muleContextFactory.createMuleContext(configBuilder);
muleContext.start();
```

This will load a Mule config file and start the MuleContext. You can then further use the Mule APIs to get Flow constructs and stop, start invoke them etc.

You can use this within your Java application without a container or further use something like Spring Boot. Here is an example using this with Spring Boot I put together previously: https://github.com/ryandcarter/mule-spring-boot-docker

Comment: That's a very good idea. Spring boot ! Way to go .. Cheers !!